# Access vba display local PDF file using web browser control

Tags: ms-access, vba

In ms access 2013, I have a user form (frm_viewer) containing a web browser control named wbContent.

I wrote the following code to populate and display a local PDF file but cannot seem to get it to function correctly.

I did manage to get it working by referencing the Control Source property of the control to a textbox on the same form (i.e. Control Source -> Base URL -> Expression Builder -> =[MyTextbox]) but I do not want to use this method, I prefer to populate it on the fly using variables.

```
Private Sub lblBrowse_Click()

'declare file dialog with late binding ->
Dim fDialog As Object, strPath As String
Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(3) 'msoFilePicker

'set parameters ->
Me.wbContent.ControlSource = ""

    'initializing the file dialog ->
    With fDialog
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Filters.Clear        '
        .title = "Please select a file..."

        'display the dialog box. If the .Show method returns True
        'the user picked a file. If the .Show method returns False
        'the user clicked Cancel.
        If .show = True Then
            strPath = .SelectedItems(1)
            Debug.Print "SELECTED_FILE: " & strPath

            'set source property to the string containing the full path ->
            Me.wbContent.ControlSource = strPath
            Me.wbContent.Requery
        Else

        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Could someone please take a look at my code and let me know how I can get it to function correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Me.wbContent.ControlSource = "='" & strPath & "'"
```

The control source needs to be a string like so: ='http://www.address.com'

Comment: Legend! That worked. It would seem the web control source property is rather different than the other typical form controls in vba forms. Its fiddly to say the least! Thanks again